# Creating an array of a class type in dafny

Tags: verification, dafny

I'm having a problem with creating an array of objects of a class type I created in dafny. The problem is when initialising a new array of that type I'm getting this error in vscode:

> unless an initializer is provided for the array elements, a new array of 'Cup' must have empty size

This is the code (actually a stripped back version that still illustrates the problem):

```
datatype Drink = WATER | LEMONADE | COFFEE | TEA

class Cup {
  var volume: int
  var drink_type: Drink
  var dirty: bool

  predicate Valid()
  reads this;
  {
    volume >= 0 
  }

  constructor (v: int, dt: Drink, d: bool)
  requires v >= 0;
  ensures Valid();
  {
    volume := v;
    drink_type := dt;
    dirty := d;
  }
}

method FilterCupDrinkType(a: array<Cup>, dt: Drink) returns (b: array<Cup>, n: int)
{
  var temp := new Cup[a.Length]; 
}
```

I looked through the manual and online but couldn't really find an answer so I'm hoping someone here knows what to do. If its not possible to do this in dafny(very new to dafny) I would appreciate any suggestions on verifying something like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a default `Cup` and then initialize the array with it as follows

```
method FilterCupDrinkType(a: array<Cup>, dt: Drink) returns (b: array<Cup>, n: int)
{
  var default := new Cup(0, WATER, false);
  var temp := new Cup[a.Length](_ => default); 
}
```

or you could allow `temp` to be an array of nullable `Cup`s (i.e., `Cup?`)

```
method FilterCupDrinkType(a: array<Cup>, dt: Drink) returns (b: array<Cup>, n: int)
{
  var temp := new Cup?[a.Length]; 
}
```

or you can copy `a` as follows

```
method FilterCupDrinkType(a: array<Cup>, dt: Drink) returns (b: array<Cup>, n: int)
{
  var temp := new Cup[a.Length](i requires 0 <= i < a.Length reads a => a[i]); 
}
```

Often a good way to find solutions for such questions, if you don't want to wait for an answer here, is to search through Dafny's extensive test suite at https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/tree/master/Test. Of course the tutorial is a better choice if treats the topic.