# Best way to create an array of range n in Dafny?

Tags: dafny

I have some trouble finding documentation on the possibility of creating arrays. The only way I know is creating an array like so: `var arr := new int[2][1,2]`. Which is rather hard given I want the range `n` in a dynamic way.

Let's say I want to create an array of range 10, so the result would be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by providing an initializing function like so: `var arr := new int[n](i => i + 1);`

If all values in your array will be `>= 0` you might consider using type `nat` instead of `int`.

A similar question here: [Creating an array of a class type in dafny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58788627/creating-an-array-of-a-class-type-in-dafny)